# VB.NET CheckedListBox Tag?

Tags: vb.net, checkedlistbox

Is there a Tag for an Item in the CheckedListBox? Or something similar? I would like to be able to store and ID associated with the item that I'm displaying.

Comment: Is this for Windows Forms, WPF, Silverlight, or ASP.NET Web Forms?  (It's almost funny there are so many possibilities these days, but I have to ask.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inherit your own control from CheckedListBox and create a property, in C# it would be like this, the rest of the functionality remains the same as it is inherited so no further additional code required:

```
public class MyCheckedListbox : System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox{
    private object thisObj;
    public object Tag{
       get{ return this.thisObj; }
       set{ this.thisObj = value; }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Decided to include the VB.NET version for everyone's benefit also...

```
Public Class MyCheckedListBox Inherits System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
    Private thisObj As Object
    Public Property Tag As Object
      Get
        Tag = thisObj
      End Get
      Set (objParam As Object)
        thisObj = objParam
      End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Of course, this is plain and uses boxing but works nicely...

Hope this helps

Comment: @Bochur1: Ok, I have edited my answer...hope there's no errors there... :)

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a Tag property.  The control accepts any object, that means you don't have to put just strings in it.  Make a class that has a string (and overrridden `ToString()`) and any other data members you need.

```
Public Class Form1

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)

        CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(New MyListBoxItem() With {.Name = "One", .ExtraData = "extra 1"})
        CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(New MyListBoxItem() With {.Name = "Two", .ExtraData = "extra 2"})
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Each obj As Object In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
            Dim item As MyListBoxItem = CType(obj, MyListBoxItem)
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}/{1} is checked.", item.Name, item.ExtraData))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyListBoxItem
    Private _name As String
    Private _extraData As String

    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ExtraData As String
        Get
            Return _extraData
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _extraData = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Name
    End Function

End Class
```

(The overridden `ToString()` dictates what will be displayed in the box.)

Answer (score 0):

Translation of tommieb75 answer to VB.NET:

```
Public Class MyCheckedListbox 
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox 
    Private thisObj As Object 
    Public Property Tag() As Object 
        Get 
            Return Me.thisObj 
        End Get 
        Set(ByVal value As Object) 
            Me.thisObj = value 
        End Set 
    End Property 
End Class
```

I use the translator at www.developerfusion.com/tools